# Why is a first-order covariant field equation for a relativistic scalar field of little or no interest?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

This question is exercise 16.1 in the book Lagrangian Interaction by Doughty, 1990.  A partial answer is given at the bottom of page 386 but the exercise asks for a number of reasons. This question has been active with me since 1990. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you added the text of the partial answer in the book you mention to your question.  Please use text when doing this as we actively discourage the posting of images of pages (which cannot be usefully searched by the system).

Answer (score 1):

My immediate thought is that there would be no way to make such a theory Lorentz invariant.

We need to contract the 4-gradient $\partial_\mu \phi$ with *something* in order to  include it in a scalar Lagrangian density.  Other than explicitly selecting a specific four vector $\alpha^\mu$, the only other choice would be to contract it with another derivative, which would yield a second-order equation of motion.

In tensor theories, the fields themselves carry spacetime indices, so you could contract the derivatives with the fields.  In spinor theories, the fields carry spinor indices which are operated on by the gamma matrices or their cousins, and you could contract the gradient with those.  But I don't see a way through to constructing a first order differential operator on scalar fields without explicitly breaking Lorentz invariance.